# Getting error in creating stored procedure with multiple insert statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

```
create procedure createAccount
(accNumber int ,  accName varchar(40) ,  amt int ,  accType int ,   addr varchar(40) ,  phno int) 
begin
START transaction;
insert into `bank`(Accno , name ,Bal ,Acctype )values(accNumber , accName , amt , accType);
insert into `personal_details`(Accno ,address ,phno )values(accNumber , addr , phno);
end;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

version : MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.9

Comment: have you defined a nev delimiter using `delimiter xx` before creating the procedue ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  The best way to get a question like this answered is to put a little effort in and include an absolutely minimal example that shows the problem, and preferably a different example that works like you expect.  So far you've just pasted your code and asked us to debug it for you.

Comment: Thanks Kordirko. Got the correct output with use of Delimiter. 
-----------------Correct procedure-----------------------
delimiter //

create procedure createAccount
(accNumber int ,  accName varchar(40) ,  amt int ,  accType int ,   addr varchar(40) ,  phno int) 
begin

insert into bank(Accno , name ,Bal ,Acctype )values(accNumber , accName , amt , accType);
insert into personal_details(Accno ,address ,phno )values(accNumber , addr , phno);

end //